# Almost Trivial $\sigma-$fields

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following Lemma form the book A probability path by sidney Resnick.

Lemma: Let $\mathcal{G}$ be an almost trivial $\sigma-\text{field}$ and let $X$ be a random variable measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$. Then there exists $c$ such that $P[X=c]=1$.

Let $F(x)=P[X\leq x]$. Then $F$ is non-decreasing and since $[X \leq x] \in \sigma(X)\subset \mathcal{G}$, $F(x)=0$ or $1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let

$c=\sup\{x: F(x)=0\}$.
The distribution must have a jump of size $1$ at $c$ and thus $P[X=c]=1$. Why $\sup\{x: F(x)=0\}$  can't be $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $F$ is a distribution function, it must satisfy 
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1
$$
This implies that there exist a $N$ such that  $F(x)>1/2$ for every $x\geq N$ (since $F$ is nondecreasing). This means that $N$ is an upper bound for the set $\{x:F(x)=0\}$ and so $\sup\{x:F(x)=0\}<\infty$.

Comment: Nice answer. To say it another way, since F is nondecreasing, if the sup were infinity then F would be identically zero, but that's not a distribution function.

Comment: What is an almost trivial $\sigma-$field?

Comment: @kentropy [Some lecture notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/280_06-07/Lecture_Notes/N5.pdf) say "**Definition 7.39.** *Let $(\Omega, \mathcal B , P) $ be a probability space. A $\sigma$-field  $\mathcal F \subset \mathcal B$ is **almost trivial** iff $P(\mathcal F) =\{0,1\}$, i.e. $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $A \in \mathcal F$*"