# Why is $X$ a.s. equal to a constant $c$?

Tags: measure-theory

$\textbf{Lemma}$: Let $\mathcal{G}$ be an almost trivial $\sigma$-field and let $X$ be a random variable measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$. Then there exists $c$ such that $P[X=c]=1$.

In the proof of the above Lemma, I read: 
$$F(x) = P[X\leq x]$$ $F$ is the cumulative distribution function, non-decreasing and since $[X\leq x]\in\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{G}$, $$F(x) = 0$$ or $$F(x)=1$$ $\forall x\in R$. Let $$c = \sup[x : F(x) = 0]$$
The distribution function must have a jump of size $1$ at $c$ $\textbf{and thus}$ $$\textbf{P[X=c]=1}$$ I cannot understand the part in bold. Why can I state that $P[X=c]=1$, that is that $X$ is a.s. equal to a constant $c$, as a consequence of what stated before?

Comment: CDFs are right continuous with left limits. Try to find the probability it’s not $c$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Almost Trivial $\sigma-$fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857263/almost-trivial-sigma-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F(x)$ is $0$ or $1$, and is a (weakly) increasing function of $x$

then there is somewhere where it changes from one to the other.

That is at $c$ by its definition.

So $P[X \le x]=0$ for all $x < c$ and $P[X \le x]=1$ for all $x > c$,

or in other words $P[X<c]=0$ and $P[X>c]=0$,

implying $P[X=c]=1$.

Comment: Thank You a lot, I got it, Your answer is extremely clear

Comment: Sorry @Henry , I was reasoning again and a doubt came up. Since $c=\sup[x : F(x) = 0]$, wouldn't it be more correct in your answer to say that $P[X\leq x] = 0$ for all $x \leq c$ and not simply for all $x < c$?
At the same time, how can I be sure that $P[X>c]=0$?

Comment: @user600927 You cannot say $P[X\leq x] = 0$ for all $x \le c$ because you do not know whether it is true for $x=c$, since a *supremum* does not have to be a member of the set it bounds.  (It turns out later it is not true here.)  Meanwhile if $P[X\leq x] = 1$ for all $x \gt c$, then $P[X\gt x] = 0$ for all $x \gt c$, and so $P[X\gt c] = 0$

Comment: Thank You again, now it is utterly clear